# Problematic increase of the width of a vertical nav bar through CSS

Tags: html, css

I wonder why an update of the following `CSS` properties: `width` , `position` does not enlarge the vertical `nav bar` on my `page.aspx`.

As an illustration, please find below the `CSS`:

```
/* The sidebar menu */
.sidenav {
    /*height: 100%;*/ /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
    width: 300px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
    /*position: fixed;*/ /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    /*background-color: #111*/; /* Black */
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Historic';
    font-size: 19px;

}

    /* The navigation menu links */
    .sidenav a {
        padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        /*font-size: 25px;*/
        font-size: 19px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI Historic';
    }

        /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
        .sidenav a:hover {
            /*color: #f1f1f1;*/
            /*color: #2196F3;*/
            color: #1912e3;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Historic';
        }

/* Style page content */
.main {
    margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidebar */
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Historic';
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidebar (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

        .sidenav a {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
}

body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI Historic";
}
```

A feedback would highly be appreciated.

Comment: It has nothing to do with C# nor ASP.NET, tags removed

Comment: This is not related with c#. But anyways, make sure you are calling the class name "sidenav" and also ensure you "sidenav" has not been defined elsewhere. If none of this solve it, use inline css with ! Important

Comment: @Selvin: sure. took note.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D: cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Randomly, based on an "*trial and error*" approach, I have empirically found out that
substituting in the `CSS` the `property` `width:300px` by `width:20%` did work. Thus I would appreciate to know, if possible, a rationale behind such `random` discovery.